# how to modify php site url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using some url like - 
**www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=about_us**

I want it to look like - 
**www.mydomain.com/about_us**

or

**www.mydomain.com/page/about_us**

How can I do this with htaccess? I will appreciate solution for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method would be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```